# python lasagne ImportError cannot import BatchNormLayer

Tags: python-2.7, theano, lasagne

When I try to play with the code [here](https://github.com/larsmaaloee/auxiliary-deep-generative-models), I met a very strange error. 
Every other modules can be imported properly, except for one.

Specifically, the error is:

```
ImportError: cannot import name BatchNormLayer
```

from the file [here](https://github.com/larsmaaloee/auxiliary-deep-generative-models/blob/master/models/sdgmssl.py). And the lasagne_extensions.layers is as following:

```
from .density_layers import *
from lasagne.layers import *
from parmesan.layers import *
```

So, I believe the problem should be that I didn't install `lasagne` or `parmesan` properly.

I have tried to upgrade the relevant modules including `numpy`, `scipy`, `theano` and `lasagne` to newest version with `pip install --upgrade` respectively. There is no `pip install` support for `parmesan`, so I downloaded it and installed it again.
However, the error remains.

Can anyone give me some advice about what I should look into?

Comment: You should probably file an issue in the Github repo instead of asking here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is to install the cutting-edge version, and `pip install --upgrade` does not do that.

But the problem can be solved by:

```
pip install --upgrade https://github.com/Theano/Theano/archive/master.zip
pip install --upgrade https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/archive/master.zip
```

Details are [here](http://lasagne.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/installation.html#bleeding-edge-version).